# Argument Error from Flask Webpage Database

Tags: python, database, flask-sqlalchemy, backreference, argument-error

I am creating a flask webpage that stores user info and accounts. This will obviously require databases. It allows me to login then returns an argument error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///logininfo.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Create tables in the database
# logininfo tab
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

class SkillTreeType(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)

class SkillTree(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    skill_tree_type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('skill_tree_type.id'), nullable=False)

    # Define the relationship between SkillTreeType and SkillTree
    skill_tree_type = db.relationship('SkillTreeType', backref='skill_trees')

    # Define the relationship between SkillTree and Skill
    skills = db.relationship('Skill', backref='associated_skill_tree', lazy='dynamic')

class Skill(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    points = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0)
    video_link = db.Column(db.String(255))  # Add this line for video links
    skill_tree_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('skill_tree.id'), nullable=False)

    # Define the relationship between Skill and SkillTree
    skill_tree_relation = db.relationship('SkillTree', backref='skills', lazy='dynamic')

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

I expect it to create the tables and then allow me to enter data into those tables.

Comment: can you post the error with full stacktrace?